# "unexpected" pairing between constructor and destructor. Why should it work like that?

Tags: c++

The code bellow is a test I created in order to understand how exactly things work. The behaviour is a little bit unexpected. If you know how many times "A created" and "A deleted" will be shown, I didn't.
The question is why it is done like that and not differently ?

```
struct A{
    int a=0x10;
     A(){std::cout<<"A created"<<std::endl;}
    ~A(){std::cout<<"A deleted"<<std::endl;}
};

void test0(A a1,A a2){
    std::cout<<"test0"<<" a1="<<a1.a<<" a2="<<a2.a<<std::endl;
}

void test1(const A a1,const A a2){
    std::cout<<"test1"<<" a1="<<a1.a<<" a2="<<a2.a<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A a,b;
    test0(a,b);
    test1(a,b);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What was your expected behaviour and what was the actual behaviour?

Comment: I thought the constructor would had been executed as many times as the destructor.

Comment: You need to add the exact expected and observed behaviour.

Comment: Sometimes the copy constructor is called instead of `A()`.

Comment: You're not counting calls to the copy constructor.

Comment: If C++ does thing A, but you expected thing B, it's no good asking us why thing A happens without telling us what thing B was supposed to be. We are obviously going to side with what _actually_ happens, and have no idea what your personal expectation was. Tell us!

Comment: Yes I know that but the question is if that is what is correct or if something else should happen instead and what exactly ? It seems that the question has been addressed in the standard by stating that "The generation of the implicitly-defined copy assignment operator is deprecated(since C++11) if T has a user-declared destructor or user-declared copy constructor."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As said previously a naive expectation would be to have executed as many constructors as destructors. As pointed out somewhere the thing is addressed in the standard in some way. The question is if the generation of the implicitly defined copy assignement is deprecated what would be the correct way to generate it ( if one exists ).

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis There should be no for 10s of people to count the expected constructer/destructer calls; then compile/run the program and look at the result.  Especially if you had made a mistake in your understanding.  I note you still have not added the requested details to the question even after you have been asked to.

Comment: @RichardCritten As I have already said, it is clear from the documentation what exactly happens (as e.g. Andrew explained bellow). The question isn't what happens but what should happen as what happens has been deprecated by the standard (C++11) meaning that it shouldn't happen anyway. ( "The generation of the implicitly-defined copy assignment operator is deprecated(since C++11) if T has a user-declared destructor or user-declared copy constructor." )

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis No. This has nothing to do with the copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Andrew It's correct, I misunderstood !

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: You're not understanding me. This information must be _in the question_, otherwise the question is likely to be closed and deleted as being not of sufficient clarity and quality for the site. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mis-counting the constructor calls. In addition to the default constructor, there are calls to the copy constructor (when passing the A objects into the functions you've defined). Adding a definition for the copy constructor shows equal numbers of (default + copy) constructor and destructor calls:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{

    int a=0x10;
     A(){std::cout<<"A created"<<std::endl;}
     A(const A&) { std::cout << "A copied" << std::endl; } // Copy constructor!
    ~A(){std::cout<<"A deleted"<<std::endl;}
};

void test0(A a1,A a2){
    std::cout<<"test0"<<" a1="<<a1.a<<" a2="<<a2.a<<std::endl;
}

void test1(const A a1,const A a2){
    std::cout<<"test1"<<" a1="<<a1.a<<" a2="<<a2.a<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a,b;
    test0(a,b);
    test1(a,b);
}
```

Output:

```
A created
A created
A copied
A copied
test0 a1=16 a2=16
A deleted
A deleted
A copied
A copied
test1 a1=16 a2=16
A deleted
A deleted
A deleted
A deleted
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2457613d5a4af0da)

The compiler will provide a default implementation of the copy constructor (if you don't define one yourself), which does a trivial bitwise copy of the member fields. That default implementation was being used when you passed the `A` objects into the functions, constructing local copies within the function body. The additional destructor calls you were seeing came from these copies. If you define your own copy constructor, you can print a message when it is called and the totals now match, as expected.